# Code shows error 'Value for attr 'T' of bool is not in the list of allowed values:'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to run this code, but even after casting it in datatype int64 it is not running. Can someone help me fix this!

**code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

out = []
num_classes = 1

for i in tf.range(num_classes):
        
        pred = tf.random.uniform(shape=[800])
        target = tf.random.uniform(shape=[800])
        
        pred = tf.cast(pred, tf.int64)
        target= tf.cast(target, tf.int64)
        i= tf.cast(i, tf.int64)
        
        out.append(tf.reduce_sum((pred == i) & (target == i)))

b= tf.stack(out)
```

**Error:**

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-24-cf4d86a56b4a> in <module>()
>      14         i= tf.cast(i, tf.int64)
>      15 
> ---> 16         out.append(tf.reduce_sum((pred == i) & (target == i)))
>      17 
>      18 b= tf.stack(out)
> 
> 1 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
> in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)    7184 def
> raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name):    7185   e.message += (" name: " +
> name if name is not None else "")
> -> 7186   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access    7187     7188 
> 
> InvalidArgumentError: Value for attr 'T' of bool is not in the list of
> allowed values: float, double, int32, uint8, int16, int8, complex64,
> int64, qint8, quint8, qint32, bfloat16, uint16, complex128, half,
> uint32, uint64    ; NodeDef: {{node Sum}}; Op<name=Sum;
> signature=input:T, reduction_indices:Tidx -> output:T;
> attr=keep_dims:bool,default=false; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_FLOAT,
> DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT16, DT_INT8, DT_COMPLEX64,
> DT_INT64, DT_QINT8, DT_QUINT8, DT_QINT32, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_UINT16,
> DT_COMPLEX128, DT_HALF, DT_UINT32, DT_UINT64];
> attr=Tidx:type,default=DT_INT32,allowed=[DT_INT32, DT_INT64]> [Op:Sum]
```

Comment: Print `out` before the `stack`.  Something is wrong with it.

Comment: @hpaulj but the error is in the `out.append` line, where I'm equating `pred= i`

Comment: The documentation for [tf.reduce](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_sum) says that the input tensor "Should have numeric type". And the input in your code is Boolean.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly got it! Actually I was trying to emulate a pytorch method `out.append(((pred == i) & (target == i)).sum())` ! Any idea how may I get over with the boolean?

Comment: Tbe error formatting was bad when I made the comment.

Comment: That doesn't look like a method specific of pytorch. You are just appending values to a list and then adding those (Booleans get converted to int when you try to sum them with `sum()`, but not with `tf.reduce_sum`). Have you tried just to write it exactly that way?

Comment: For booleans use `tf.math.reduce_all` or `tf.math.reduce_any`.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `out.append(tf.reduce_sum((pred == i) & (target == i)))`
with either:

```
out.append(tf.math.count_nonzero((pred == i) & (target == i)))
```

or

```
out.append(tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.cast((pred == i) & (target == i), dtype=tf.int64)))
```

solves the posed problem...

**However**, this just results in a very convoluted way to create a shape (num_classes,) tensor with 800 as its first entry and trailing zeros.

If OP could please clarify the intent of the code snippet, we may be able to reach that goal in a better way.

### Edit

Something like this may be closer to what OP is trying to accomplish:

```
import tensorflow as tf


@tf.function
def make_b(num_classes, rand_shape, dtype=tf.int64):
    logg = tf.TensorArray(dtype=dtype, size=num_classes, infer_shape=False, element_shape=[])

    for i in tf.range(num_classes, dtype=dtype):
        pred = tf.random.uniform(shape=rand_shape, dtype=dtype, maxval=num_classes+1)
        targ = tf.random.uniform(shape=rand_shape, dtype=dtype, maxval=num_classes+1)
        both = tf.cast((pred == i) & (targ == i), dtype=dtype)

        logg = logg.write(tf.cast(i, tf.int32), tf.math.reduce_sum(both))

    return logg.stack()


b = make_b(1, (800,))
```